# [Ext.Loader]: Some requested files failed to load

Tags: extjs, karma-runner

While running command as **karma start karma.conf.js** for **extjs application unit testing with mocha**, it is throwing the above error.
My code looks like this:
I have set the paths variable as:

```
**var paths** = {
        'Demo': 'packages/demo/src',
        'NewR3': 'extjs/r3/app',
        'BasicFiles' : 'packages',
        'Portal': 'extjs/portal/app',
        'Ext.ux': 'frameworks/extjs/src/ux'
    };

Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: paths,
    disableCaching: true    
});

Ext.require([
    'Ext.ux.grid.*',
    'Ext.ux.data.*',
    'Ext.ux.toolbar.Paging',
    'Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect',
    'Ext.ux.IFrame'
]);

Ext.require([
    'BasicFiles.deft.deft-debug',
    'BasicFiles.PM.PM-debug',
    'Portal.util.PortalDataProvider',
    'Portal.util.PortalUtil',

]);
```

WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/extjs/portal/app/util/Startup.js?_dc=1483346775630
WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/extjs/portal/app/util/ResourceLoader.js?_dc=1483346775630
WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/extjs/portal/app/view/Viewport.js?_dc=1483346775630
Warnings I get after running the above command:

Comment: In this case some call is getting failed which was requested to the server.  Something wrong with server which could not find what was requested. Make sure all the files are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run command as **karma start karma.conf.js**, the server fetch all the files included in karma.conf.js from the base path of your project.

When you also require the files from Ext.Loader , it is unable to load the paths since the server is loading from base path, and the paths conflicts with Ext.Loader.

Include all the files that are to be loaded in karma.conf.js itself instead of including it from Ext.require, and the server will load all the files with status 200 without any conflicts.

karma.conf.js file

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],

    plugins: [
              'karma-mocha',
              'karma-chai',
              'karma-coverage',
              'karma-chrome-launcher',
              'karma-html-reporter',

            ],


    files: [
       // **All files here**

    ],

    reporters: ["dots", "progress", "coverage", "html"],

    port: 9876,

    coverageReporter: {
        type: 'html',
        dir: 'coverage/'
    },

    preprocessors: {
        //coverage files here
    },

    htmlReporter: {
        outputDir: 'karma_dir'
    },
    colors: true,

    proxies: {
        "data/": "http://localhost:9876/base/data"
    },

    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

    autoWatch: false,

     browsers: ["Chrome"],

    singleRun: true
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned in comment you may missing some filepath. Well I assume after changing the path of url it is giving desire result.